# What are my options to get the BMP180 to work?

Tags: bmp180

I stumbled upon some old tutorials and bought the BMP180 sensor to use with my Pi 4. However, there is a new model and the [repository](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_BMP/) containing functions to use the sensor with the Pi is deprecated and archived. When I download the repo and run `sudo python setup.py install` to install the functions, it seems it doesn't find what it's searching for.

Is there a beginner-friendly way to get this pressure sensor work?

Comment: Rpi3 BMP180 Barometer Sensor Interface Problem - Asked 1 year, 7 months ago Active 1 year, 4 months ago Viewed 1k times
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60274562/rpi3-bmp180-barometer-sensor-interface-problem/60292757#60292757

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. The repo you used is stale, and abandoned by its author - that *may be* a problem. Try to find another repo that's more frequently used and maintained - [this one might be better](https://github.com/nickoala/sensor), and it comes with some decent instructions.
2. Did you remember to [enable your I2C](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-i2c/) interface?

Comment: Yes, I enabled i2c, which was among the first steps in most tutorials (quite some tutorials were copy and paste from the inactive repo, though, and also asked for obsolete steps such as editing some black list). Thanks, the repo you mentioned has the solution!

Comment: @ManuelPopp: Thanks for the feedback - I'm glad to hear it helped.

Answer (score 0):

There should be dozens of Python modules for that device.  I suggest googling for "Python BMP180 Raspberry Pi".

I think the BME280 is compatible.

See my [BME280](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_BME280_py) software example.